# .htaccess redirect to another video if HTTP_ORIGIN and user agent are not like this

Tags: .htaccess

i want users to access my videos only if

> RULE1:

**HTTP_ORIGIN**  is ***Example.Com***   and  **HTTP_REFERER** is ***Exammple.Com/xxxxxxxx***

> RULE 2

**HTTP_USER_AGENT** is ***useragent1*** OR ***useragent2***  OR ***useragent3***

- So if one rule is correct  then will videos will open normal

if both rules are inccorect then  redirect to another video example redirect.mp4

```
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/redirect.mp4[R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to separate this into separate rule blocks. For example, try something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Test RULE#1 and set an env var if true
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Origin} =http://example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} =http://example.com/xxxxxxxx
RewriteRule ^ - [E=RULE1:1]    

# Test RULE#2 and set an env var if true
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =useragent1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =useragent2 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =useragent3
RewriteRule ^ - [E=RULE2:1]    

# If neither rule is correct (and not already redirected) then redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect\.mp4$
RewriteCond %{ENV:RULE1} !1
RewriteCond %{ENV:RULE2} !1
RewriteRule \.mp4$ /redirect.mp4 [R,L]
```

I assume you only want this to apply to requests for `.mp4` videos?  (Is an *internal rewrite* not preferable - instead of a redirect? In which case just remove the `R` flag from the last `RewriteRule` directive.)

The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* makes it a lexicographical string comparison, as opposed to a regex, so do not backslash escape otherwise special characters (like dots).